# Eclipse RCP generates plugin.xml which indent with spaces

Tags: eclipse, rcp, plugin.xml

Recently I need to setup Eclipse RCP 3.7 (Indigo) for indenting with tabs in XML-files. I've set *Preferences* → *XML* → *XML Files* → *Editor* → ◉  *Indent using tabs*, but visual constructor of `plugin.xml` generates space-indented xml whatever.

How can I do that - to force visual constructor of `plugin.xml` to generate tabs-indented XML-file?

Thank you for your advices and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. The XML files generated by the Plugin Development Environment (PDE) component of Eclipse are always generated with spaces and there is no configuration to change this.

PDE doesn't use the generic XML editor that you configured in the Preferences.